# Retrieve return value of function pointer, which is provided as parameter to other function

Tags: c

This might be a bit specific, but I want to know, how to return a ... let's see the code first actually.

```c
void *atomic_op(void * (*f)(),void* ret) // Using a function pointer to encapsulate the procedure in between locks
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
    ret = f;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
}
```

I want to be able to get the return value of `f` and store it to `ret` using void pointers for more general use.
My IDE informs me that `argument ret` is not accessed outside the scope of this function, but later down my code there is

```c
    char* temp;

    while (1)
    {
        atomic_op(readBuffer(shared_array),temp);
        if (*temp == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        atomic_op(printOutBuffer(shared_array),NULL);
    }
```

When running the whole thing, the IDE comes our right (of course) but I cannot understand why.

The whole thing is an attempt on monitors, with 2 threads sharing an array in a consumer producer relationship (just experimenting) and I stumbled across this which I found really weird!

Can someone explain what happens here?

The whole thing is here https://controlc.com/2af8f50c

Link with pthread

Comment: You can't get a return value from `f` without calling `f`, regardless of what you want to do with that value.

Comment: `ret = f;` doesn't actually call the function. Also, the new value of `ret` won't be seen by the caller, and your function should return a value.

Comment: Why people insist in using `void` pointers in their questions? The problem is most probably (and I will not enter to read it in full) because you are ignoring completely the by far insufficient type checking done by the C compiler.  So I cannot be interested in solving your problem, because you don't pay attention to the important concepts of good programming practice.

Answer (score 2):

First off, this doesn't actually call the function:

```
ret = f;
```

It just takes the function pointer and assigns it to `ret`.  To call the function you want `f()`.

Also, because parameters in C are passed by value, changes to the parameter `ret` aren't reflected in the calling function.  That fact that `ret` is a pointer type doesn't matter.

If you want a function to update a pointer value it needs to take a pointer to a pointer.  That pointer-to-pointer parameter must then be dereferenced to update the pointer variable in the calling function.

Making these fixes, your function would look like this:

```
void *atomic_op(void * (*f)(),void **ret)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
    if (ret) {
      *ret = f();
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
}
```

And you would call it like this:

```
char *tmp;
void *tmp2;
atomic_op(readBuffer(shared_array),&tmp2);
tmp = tmp2;
```

Here the extra `void *` variable is required because a `char **` is not guaranteed to be safely converted to a `void **`.

There's still one thing we haven't addressed, and that's that the function is defined to return a `void *` but doesn't actually return anything.  This is OK for your program since you're not attempting to access the return value, but still it's a bad code smell.

It would be better to take the return value of `f` and make that the return value of `atomic_op` and get rid of the second parameter.  This also means you don't need a second variable in the calling function.

So now we have:

```
void *atomic_op(void * (*f)())
{
    void *ret;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
    ret = f();
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
    return ret;
}
```

Which would be called like this:

```
char *tmp;
tmp = atomic_op(readBuffer(shared_array));
```

All this is assuming that `readBuffer` and `printOutBuffer` return function pointers.  If they don't, you need to pass just the name of the function and the function's parameters to `atomic_op`, and the type of `f` would need to match the type of `readBuffer` and `printOutBuffer`.  That would give you:

```
void *atomic_op(void *(*f)(void *), void *param)
{
    void *ret;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
    ret = f(param);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
    return ret;
}
```

Which is called like this:

```
char *tmp;
tmp = atomic_op(readBuffer, shared_array);
```

Comment: Aha, this tells me I went too deep too soon. Anything you recommend as study material for function pointers? Can you make atomic_op variadic to increase re-usability?
edit: Isn't the void* ret unsafe to return in atomic_op? It does go out of scope when out of the function, doesn't it?